# Arduino Mega2560 can't be programmed repeatedly using avrdude

Tags: arduino, timeout, avrdude

I have a sketch for a mega2560 board that I can upload successfully using the Arduino IDE using the upload button but I would prefer to use a script using avrdude. The only problem is if I try to run avrdude more than once to flash the board it get's a stk500v2_ReceivedMessage(): timeout. It doesn't happen every time but enough. The only way the avrdude seems to work again is if I update the same sketch using the Arduino IDE.

I was having trouble finding what the Arduino IDE does to upload a file but all the settings I could find suggest that avrdude is doing it the same way.

Comment: If you enable verbose output for upload in Arduino settings, it'll show you whole command used for the upload. So you can compare differences.

Comment: Thank you so much! @KIIV I didn't notice that before. I was trying to look at the arduino source code which didn't really work.

Comment: Ok, I'll make an answer

Comment: @KIIV The arduino output window doesn't keep a long enough history to see the commands being called.

Comment: I've added it into the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verbose compilation and upload can be enabled in Arduino IDE Settings:

```
File->Preferences->Show verbose output during:  [] compilation  [x] upload.
```

It will show complete commands used for upload and the `avrdude` should be same or you can use the same `avrdude.exe`. You should see something like:

```
C:\arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avrdude -CC:\arduino\hardware\tools\avr/etc/avrdude.conf -v -V -patmega2560 -cwiring -PCOM17 -b115200 -D -Uflash:w:C:\Users\kiiv\AppData\Local\Temp\build658cdf44885ca2a8676f164a933c092f.tmp/MAX7219_4x4x4.ino.hex:i
```

BTW: I've just started with `PlatformIO CLI` (command line tool) and I'm loving it.

`PlatformIO IDE` didn't work well for me, as I'm using czech keyboard layout and keystrokes prevents me to write all essential characters like `[]{}#&` without switching it to english one.